# 8Mhz Bootloader for Arduino Micro

Tags: bootloader, atmega

I have just finished a project using an Arduino Micro dev board and want to move to a standalone ATmega32.

I need to run this at 3.3V and I dont want to go down the overclocking road so I have an 8MHz crystal to put on it.

I still want to be able to upload sketches via USB and the Arduino compiler so I gather I need to burn a different bootloader.

For this purpose I have purchased a USBASP programmer.

I am slightly unsure of what to do next - everything I can find on the topic either relates to the ATmega328 or to burning bootloaders using another Arduino.

I have worked out that I need to modify boards.txt to point to the correct bootloader....but which is the correct bootloader for ATmega32 at 8Mhz?

Also do I need to change any fuses?

Thanks

Comment: AVR studio is what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure at all, but i'd try with the original Optiboot project. I say that there is a Mega32 bootloader; you can try to download the archive, then modify the boards-1.6,txt file to add another variant. You can use the same binary as the original one (which runs at 16MHz) but change the clock speed and, maybe, the baud rate (just halve it if the bootloader does not reply). Change the bootloader tool (not sure how to do it, but I think you need to set the USBASP). Then try it... Check the fuses on the datasheet to be sure. And... Why the 8MHz crystal? Usually I avoid it since the 328 has...

Comment: ... an internal oscillator at 8MHz, so I can use it simply changing the fuses (and saving one crystal and two capacitors). I only use crystals where I need higher precision, but then usually run at 16MHz...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. My project is a race timing system requiring a very precise clock that can keep its time well. So I am not sure the internal clock will cut the mustard.

Comment: That's not about the C programming language and not about Arduino. And  you should first read the ATmega datasheets. Raw programming does not require a bootloader.

Comment: @Olaf The datasheet says you can calibrate the internal RC oscillator to ±1% accuracy. If you're timing anything involving humans, I think that's fine.

Comment: @unwind: I don't really see the relation here. OP already wrote he will add a quartz. Re the RC-osc: not sure if that is sufficient for USB (presumably for low-speed). Not only because of the variation, but the jitter. Anyway, this is not well suited for this site.

Comment: @Olaf He said he wants to still be able to load the sketches through usb and the arduino environment, so it requires the bootloader.. As for the project, you'll have to select the right source you need. For instance crystals often have errors in the range of 10-50ppm, which means 6-30ms of error over a 10 minutes race. With the internal oscillator it is 6s over 10 minutes. Just do the math and select the right source (for one race timer I designed at university we needed a much lower time, so we used a precision crystal with - if I recall well - an overall precision of 4ppm)

Comment: @frarugi87: My ARM JTAG-interface also uses USB. I don't see this directly related. OP clearly wrote "standalone ATmega", which excludes using the Arduino bootloader and -ecosystem.

Comment: No, wait, I totally misread the question. I thought you were using a arduino pro mini, bit a micro has a built-in usb. If you want to keep using the USB with the Atmega 32, you will need a USB-to-UART bridge (a couple of dollars anywhere) or you should impolement your own USB stack to interact with the arduino software

Comment: @Olaf Why does "standalone atmega" exclude arduino? Searching on google for "standalone atmega" the [first result](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard) is clearly related to arduino. You can flash an arduino bootloader on any standalone board, or make the arduino ide compile the sketches and upload them through the JTAG port, but this implies that you are actually using the arduino environment

Comment: @frarugi87: So if google shows a match for "sun rises in the west", you also believe that? Might be tough news, but google results don't always show the truth. Arduino includes a whole ecosystem of software, including the specific bootloader. "Standalone ATmega" does exclude using this. The IDE might be usable if it supports bootloader-less upload/debugging, but then either with C or C++, not the Arduino-variant of C++.

Comment: Just to clarify by "standalone Arduino" I intend to recreate most of what exists on the Arduino Micro board including Micro, crystal, Micro USB port, reset button. The reason for doing this is I am going to use the 5V USB voltage to power a Lithium battery charging circuit - then run the Arduino at 3.3V via a LVD regulator. I thought the ATMega32 used hardware USB and therefor I thought this would still work at 8Mhz...and the rest of the Arduino environment...but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: @Olaf I see, pointless as usual to have a discussion with you.. Anyway as far as I know standalone atmega means a processor without the "arduino branded" pcb, not atmega without anything else. If you can point me towards someone who is saying that "standalone" means without any reference to arduino... And usually everybody calling it "standalone" as a first step tell you how to flash a bootloader, anyway.. Discussion closed for me

Comment: @NickThornton The Atmega32u4, which is the micro on the arduino micro, has hw usb. The atmega32 is a different microcontroller, without HW USB

Comment: Massive apologies! I have the atmega32u4. I assumed they were similar devices in different packages.

Comment: @frarugi87  You should do more bare-metal development with other systems than Arduino. You would know better what "standalone" means and that most such systems don't use a bootloader at all (sometimes one is added for later updates once the product is released into the field). Widen your horizon. And I would consider myself and my friends and colleagues "someone". So there is one reference to someone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087563/8mhz-bootloader-for-arduino-micro?noredirect=1#comment71347091_42087563

Comment: @Olaf Well we all have to start somewhere dont we? I made a few mistakes in this post. I apologize  for that. I find your attitude quite condescending... reference to someone? I have no idea what this means!

Comment: @NickThornton: You missed the context. It was not me asking for "someone".

Comment: @Olaf I find self-referencing a poor argumentation... I'm not saying "all barebones are arduino". Of course there are tons of other microcontrollers, and only a few are actually programmable through arduino (and BTW only recently I started using arduino, I always used other environments - from Microchip, Silabs, Texas, Renesas). You are, on the other hand, claiming that barebone means without bootloader. No, at least not in what I mean barebone. And the creators of arduino (in the page I linked you) agree with me. Like a lot of not-my-friend-or-colleague people agree too. So...

Comment: @frarugi87: Can you point at where I wrote "barebone"?

Comment: @Olaf sorry, I meant standalone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit out of luck.

The ATmega doesn't have hardware USB, so I assume the bootloader is using [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) to implement USB. That stack, being a software implementation of USB's high-speed signalling, requires at least a 12 MHz clock (higher is better).

I don't think you can run V-USB using only the internal 8 MHz oscillator.

Comment: I wonder how operational that is if some other software is running. Even an interrupt would cause trouble. Correction: the linked page says it requires at least 12MHz, the 12.8 is for the internal RC-osc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the OP comments the micro is indeed an Atmega32u4, not an Atmega32 (@OP: please fix the question to match this).

Since it has onboard USB, you can use a pre-existing bootloader like the sparkfun one:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12587

Here you have the link to one of their products, the Arduino pro micro 3.3V (which runs at 8MHz). You can add the [sparkfun arduino boards](https://github.com/sparkfun/Arduino_Boards) repository to your IDE and then just use the board specification for their pro micro 3.3V do upload the correct bootloader and to program it through the USB just like the usual Arduino Micro.

Comment: Thankyou - this I think is definitely the way forward!

Comment: @NickThornton Ok, then try it and see if it works. If it does, please mark the answer as accepted so that people looking for the same problem can easily find the solution